# OMNET++ How to customize a wireless host that extends AODVRouter with RandomWP Mobility

Tags: omnet++, inet

I'm currently working on a MANET project and wanted to create a customized wireless host to mimic a selfish node that would immediately drop a message it receives in the MANET. 
I have created a simple module called SelfishNode.NED, the code as follows:

```
simple SelfishNode {
parameters:
@display("i=block/buffer");

gates:
    input radioIn[numRadios] @directIn;
    inout pppg[] @labels(PPPFrame-conn);
    inout ethg[] @labels(EtherFrame-conn);
}
```

2. Then, I created its C++ file with the code below:

```
#include "SelfishNode.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>

void SelfishNode::initialize()
{

}

void SelfishNode::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
delete msg;
}
```

3. Next, I created a compound module called snode.NED that extends AODVRouter, the code as follows:

```
import inet.node.aodv.AODVRouter;

    module snode extends AODVRouter
    {
    parameters:
    @networkNode;
    @display("i=device/wifilaptop");
    @labels(wireless-node);

    submodules:
        bad: SelfishNode {
        @display("p=273,350");
        }
    }
```

4. Next, I created a network module called ManetA.NED:

   ```
   import inet.common.figures.DelegateSignalConfigurator;
   import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.IPv4NetworkConfigurator;
   import inet.physicallayer.ieee80211.packetlevel.Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium;
   import inet.visualizer.integrated.IntegratedCanvasVisualizer;
   import inet.environment.common.PhysicalEnvironment;

   network ManetA
   {
   parameters:
   int numHosts;
   int numBadNodes;

   submodules:
   visualizer: IntegratedCanvasVisualizer {
       @display("p=59,103");
   }
   configurator: IPv4NetworkConfigurator {
       @display("p=59,164");
   }
   radioMedium: Ieee80211ScalarRadioMedium {
       @display("p=60,50,i=misc/sun");
   }
   figureHelper: DelegateSignalConfigurator {
       @display("p=61,236");
   }

   hostBad[numBadNodes]: snode {
       @display("i=device/palm");
   }

   physicalEnvironment: PhysicalEnvironment {
       @display("p=59,306");
       }
   }
   ```
5. Lastly, I configured the mobility type and the number of bad nodes in omnetpp.ini as follows:

   ```
   *.numBadNodes = ${HOST=5}
   *.hostBad.mobilityType = "inet.mobility.single.RandomWPMobility"
   ```

Is this correct?
And also when I run the simulation, the nodes didn't move at all. I have studied for the whole day but couldn't resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost correct... if you operate in the INET namespace, you don't need to provide the full name of the mobility module when you set the `mobilityType`

```
**.hostBad.mobilityType = "RandomWPMobility"
```

Check the example configs in `/inet/examples/mobility/omnetpp.ini` for further details.

Comment: Thanks MichaelKirsche. Now I wanted to inherit all the functions in AODVRouting.cc but override AODVRouting::sendAODVPacket() function with my own codes in the C++ file. How can I do that? I got "redefinition of handleMessage" error with the following code in my c++ file:
**void AODVRouting::sendAODVPacket(AODVControlPacket *packet,     const L3Address& destAddr, unsigned int timeToLive, double delay)
    {
    EV << "Received message `" << msg->getName() << "', dropping message now\n";
    delete msg;
    }**

Comment: Better to post a new question and format it correctly than comment under another question...